# 'Connection was reset' error in Chrome

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, router

I am getting **The site can't be reached** *Connection was reset* error most of the time while surfing in Chrome. Like it was tough for me to even open superuser.com. The same website opens up in Mozilla Firefox and my Android Chrome app in a jiffy. But sometimes my phone's chrome also give the same error. My phone and my pc are connected to the same router. What could be the problem?

OS: Windows 7

Chrome Version: 53.0.2785.116 m (That's the latest one)

Mobile Chrome Version: 52.0.2743.98

Comment: Does the problem persists if you use https connection?

Comment: @James Yup, problem persists. This problem isn't with all websites that I open. Like facebook and twitter isn't giving me a problem. But Wolfram Alpha, stack overflow, etc seems unreachable. The same problem now has started to occur in my mobile chrome. I installed Opera Mini and it seems to work fine. Then what is the problem with chrome?